# Delete Data from One Table using multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to delete some data from one table using multiple table.  The problem i am having with this query is that it is deleting data that is not suppose to delete.  I want to delete only the Data where ID's in both tables are DIFFERENT.  In other words, i want to keep when the ID's in both tables are the same.  Here is my query:

```
delete  Tabel1
from Table1 r join
Table2 w on r.ID <> w.ID
and w.Date_Assigned is not null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do:

```
delete Tabel1 where Id not in (select Id from Table2)
```

Your statement will probably delete all records from `Tabel1`, because for every record it will find at least one in `Tabel2` with a different `ID`.

To test this, just run

```
select r.ID
from Table1 r join
Table2 w on r.ID <> w.ID
and w.Date_Assigned is not null
```

and you'll understand what the problem is.